# Implementar RecycleView

Tags: java, android

Buenas gente, me encuentro tratando de implementar un recycleView, la cosa es la siguiente, yo tengo varios layout, los cuales tienen bastantes campos (editText, textView, etc). Al ser tantos los campos no puedo cargarlos todos de una sino se sobrecarga mucho, necesito una forma de cargarlos de manera progresiva por así llamarlo, alguien tiene algun ejemplo de como implementar el recycleView cargando las layout a medida que realice un scroll? O alguna otra forma de como solventar este problema. Gracias!!

Answer (score 1):

Si no tienes dos view que tengan la misma disposición de widgets (lo que en inglés se llama layout) no tiene ningún sentido implementar el recycleView.

Lo lógico es que categorices los tipos de objetos de la lista, y decidas qué contiene cada tipo:

Tipo 1: 1 EditView y un ButtonView

Tipo 2: 1 Button View y 2 ImageView

etc...

a cada objeto de tu array(o cursor, o lo que sea que representes), le asignas un tipo de la lista anterior, y al cargarlo en tu adaptador, reciclas una vista del mismo tipo.

Comment: Pero no se podria hacer por ejemplo que al hacer scroll hacia abajo, cargue la otra parte del formulario, yo lo quiero hacer esto ya que poseo un formulario con muuuchos campos y no puedo cargarlos todos de golpe. Gracias por tu respuesta!

Comment: Pero el recycle view, lo que hace es rehusar las vistas (View) que se desplazaron fuera de la pantalla, pero cambiando los datos. 

Si tienes una lista con varios elementos, cada elemento tiene una vista. Cuando te desplaces hacia abajo, la vista 3 (por ejemplo) aparecerá y desaparecerá la 1. Si tú reciclas la vista 1 y le añades los campos demás que tiene tu vista 3, cuando vuelvas a desplazarte a la vista 1, tendrás que borrarle los campos añadidos. 
Recycle view vale para vistas que son iguales pero con distintos datos, para tu caso no es aplicable.